# Exception When trying to execute a R script in java using Renjin

Tags: java, r, renjin

I created a R Script "script.R"

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=(1:10)+rnorm(n=10))
print(df)
print(lm(y ~ x, df))
```

Tried to invoke using renjin in Java as

```
engine.eval(new FileReader("src/javaSrc/script.R"));
```

Got the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.renjin.parser.RParser.parseSource(Lcom/google/common/io/CharSource;)Lorg/renjin/sexp/ExpressionVector;
    at
org.renjin.script.RenjinScriptEngine.eval(RenjinScriptEngine.java:125)
    at
org.renjin.script.RenjinScriptEngine.eval(RenjinScriptEngine.java:109)
    at javaSrc.TryRenjin.main(TryRenjin.java:27)
```

Comment: please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two different versions of Renjin on your classpath: Renjin recently migrated to using Guava 17.0, and all references to InputSupplier were changed to CharSource.

Either use the latest release version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.renjin</groupId>
    <artifactId>renjin-script-engine</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0-RC7</version>
</dependency>
```

Or the latest snapshot

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.renjin</groupId>
    <artifactId>renjin-script-engine</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0-RC8-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
```

But mixing and matching jars from different versions (say renjin-core-0.7.0-RC7.jar with renjin-script-engine-0.7.0-RC8-SNAPSHOT.jar) will lead to the kind of errors you see above.